# NestedQuery in BoolQuery using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to understand how query in EL works, with lots of problems to be honest.

Here my documents with properties:

```
{"statusError":null,
"fileHash":"da8620bad21685c5e385fb1b43a7e744",
"project":{"id":7687},
"error":null,
"ocrFile64":"JVBERi0xL...."
"isInElastic":false,
"originalName":"test.pdf",
"lastUpdated":"2018-10-18T12:47:59Z",
"dateCreated":"2018-10-18T12:40:19Z",
"ocrAvailable":true,
"attachment":{"date":"2018-07-05T07:20:06Z",
"content_type":"application/pdf",
"language":"en","title":"Untitled",
"content":"blah blah blahblahblahblahblah"
"company":{"id":1},
"id":25850,
"tag":[{"id":3},{"id":2}],
"contentType":"application/pdf",
"imageHash":"",
"label":null,
"size":47680,
"user":{"id":7563},
"md5":[100,97,56,54,50,48,98,97,100,50,49,54,56,53,99,53,101,51,56,53,102,98,49,98,52,51,97,55,101,55,52,52],
"status":{"name":"CLASSIFIED"}}
```

EL has Ingest Module plug in installed for uploading content of file. Indeed the pipeline is ocrFile64 and the content of file is inside content properties.

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, I'd like to make a query like: give me all the document where originalName contains "test" and user.id is equal to 1 and content contains "blah".

So far I have written this:

```
client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder)
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("testEL")
searchRequest.types("test")
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();

boolQuery.filter(new MatchPhrasePrefixQueryBuilder("originalName", "test"))

boolQuery.filter(new NestedQueryBuilder("user", new MatchQueryBuilder("user.id", "1"), ScoreMode.None))

boolQuery.filter(new MatchPhrasePrefixQueryBuilder("content", "blah"))

searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery)
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

If I query just the orignalName it works. If I add the content not anymore, if I add the nested query it results in an error:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]
```

Thanks

Here the mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "attachment": {
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "content_length": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "company": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "contentType": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "dateCreated": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "fileHash": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "imageHash": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "isClassified": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isInElastic": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "lastUpdated": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "md5": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "ocrAvailable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "ocrFile64": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "originalName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "project": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "size": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "status": {
          "properties": {
            "enumType": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "storageName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tag": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "user": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your Elasticsearch mapping?

Comment: Added in the original post - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch is complaining because your `"user"` field is not a `nested` type field. You can use a standard `match` or a `term` query on `"user.id"`.

The JSON query would look something like this:

```
POST <your_index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "originalName": "test"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "user.id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "blah"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed also the content issue, it was a filter field, my bad.